# How to pass #available as function parameter in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I need help in optimizing this piece of code. The only difference is one is checking for iOS 13 and other is checking for iOS 14. Is there a way to pass it as function parameter?

```
func setImage(_ name: String, assetName: String, button: UIButton) {
    var buttonImage: UIImage
    if #available(iOS 13, *) {
        buttonImage = UIImage(systemName: name) ?? UIImage()
    } else {
        buttonImage = UIImage(named: name) ?? UIImage()
    }
    button.setImage(buttonImage, for: .normal)
}

func setFaxMachineImage(_ name: String, assetName: String, button: UIButton) {
    var buttonImage: UIImage
    if #available(iOS 14, *) {
        buttonImage = UIImage(systemName: name) ?? UIImage()
    } else {
        buttonImage = UIImage(named: name) ?? UIImage()
    }
    button.setImage(buttonImage, for: .normal)
}
```

Comment: Why do you have two functions that do the same thing but one has a different name and one checks for iOS 14 instead of 13?

Answer (score 1):

You only need one function here. Assuming you have a need to support iOS 12 or earlier then you can do:

```
func setImage(_ name: String, assetName: String, button: UIButton) {
    let buttonImage: UIImage?
    if #available(iOS 13, *) {
        buttonImage = UIImage(systemName: name) ?? UIImage(named: name)
    } else {
        buttonImage = UIImage(named: name)
    }
    button.setImage(buttonImage, for: .normal)
}
```

No need to fallback to `UIImage()`. Just make `buttonImage` optional.

This code will try to create an image for a given "SF Symbol" if it exists, otherwise it will try to find a matching image in your asset catalog/resource bundle. This allows you to support newer "SF Symbols" on older versions of iOS by providing your own version.

Let's say you wanted to use the "faxmachine" SF Symbol. This symbol was added in iOS 14. If your app is run under iOS 12 or 13 then the SF Symbol won't be found so you must be sure to include an image named "faxmachine" in your image assets so it will be used for those earlier iOS versions.

Basically, if your app supports iOS 12 or earlier, you need to create your own version of every SF Symbol you want to use to ensure the image will appear correctly for all iOS versions your app runs on.